# Why does numberArray.sort() not sort numbers correctly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm practicing the data visualization library d3.js, and I am using a random data generator identical to the following:

```
function generateRandomData() {
    var i,
        data = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i += 1) {
        data.push(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return data;
}
```

I store the value and try to sort it as shown below:

```
var data = generateRandomData();
data.sort();
```

Unfortunately, the sorted dataset is not sorted completely - some of the values are actually incorrect. For example, I would have numbers such as [12, 15, 18, 21, 3, 18 ...]. What is the cause of the sort function's inaccuracy?

Note: I found a proper solution, which solved my problem:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) { return b - a; });
```

I simply want to know why sort() is unreliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort()` function considers everything in the Array as String if it is called without custom ordering function.

The only exception is `undefined`, which is from Javascript 1.2 always the "largest" item in the sorted array.

```
[void(0),342,4.5,"ahahaha",null,"zzz", "nen", "nup", 0/0, "KDSFL", "-sdfh",-3324, "-%",Array.prototype.sort,window,Array.zzz,"[oooooo]", "undefined",0].sort()
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Unfortunately, while correct (+1), this disagrees with the "results" given in the post...

Comment: OP's example result of `[12, 15, 18, 21, 3, 18 ...]` is likely just an example, as running `sort()` on that array (minus the ellipses) results in [12,15,18,18,21,3], which is the proper sort order assuming all values are strings

Comment: @pst true; i thought you were questioning the validity of the answer

Comment: @jackwanders Yes, you're right, my "result" was just an example, because I didn't want to copy and paste the long result that I had. So why is it that it matters that they're strings and not numbers?

Comment: @JimJohnson: They are considered as String, since `sort()` function must sort everything you have in the Array, from Number, String, to Function, NaN, null, Array, Object, etc. so it has to rely on a common denominator to define the order.

Comment: If you don't provide `sort()` with a sorting function, it converts all values to strings and runs a alphabetic comparison. Therefore, 12 < 2. If you want to sort numerically, you have to provide a sorting function