# How arr.sort() in nodeJS works?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am getting a strange result using arr.sort() below is the code

```
const arr=[1,99,102,121,2,2,3,7]
arr.sort()
console.log(arr)
```

I am getting the following output

```
[
  1, 1000, 121,  2,
  2,    3,   7, 99
]
```

can someone please explain what is happening and why?

Comment: Also relevant: [How does Javascript's sort() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1494713) | [Why doesn't the sort function of javascript work well?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093874) | [Array.sort() doesn't sort numbers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7000851) | [How to sort an array of integers correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007) | [Why does numberArray.sort() not sort numbers correctly in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11218670) | [Why do javascript sort a numeric array not in numeric order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19740047)

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)? It explains in the first paragraph that it sorts the values as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The default sort order is ascending, built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values.

Thus your values are converted to strings first and then compared lexicographic. Ie `"101"` is less than `"2"`

If you want to do a numerical sort, you have to provide a compare function

```js
const arr=[1,99,102,121,2,2,3,7]
arr.sort((a,b) => a-b);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) accepts a function as parameter:

> compareFunction Optional
> Specifies a function that defines the sort order. **If omitted, the array elements are converted to strings**, then sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value.

You need `arr.sort((a,b) => a - b)`